# Any Javascript optimization benchmarks?

Tags: javascript, optimization, benchmarking

I watched Nicholas Zakas' talk, [Speed up your Javascript](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHtdZgou0qU), with some interest. I liked how he benchmarked the various performance improvements created by various optimization techniques, e.g. reducing calls to deeply nested objects, changing loops to count down instead of up, etc.

I would like to run these benchmarks myself though, to see exactly how our current browsers are faring. I guess it wouldn't be too difficult to cook up some timed loops, but I'd like to know if there are any existing implementations out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [JSLitmus](http://www.broofa.com/Tools/JSLitmus/), you can see a sample of it in action [here](http://www.broofa.com/Tools/JSLitmus/simple_test.html)